# Is possible check if a record exists synchronous?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Basically I want store a `user` inside the database, before doing this operation I need to validate the fields of that `user`. So I have this structure:

```
exports.save = function(req, res)
{
   let errors = validate(req.body);

   if(!errors.length)
   {
       //add user
       res.status(200).send(true);
   }
   else{
       res.status(500).send("oh bad");
   }
};

function validate(user)
{
   let errors = [];

   if (User.findOne({ email: user.email })) {
      errors.push({ msg: 'Email already registered!' });
   }
}
```

the code above simply cannot works because `NodeJS` handle the operation asynchronous. I can fix this "problem" doing something like:

```
User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
  if (!user) {
    //add user
    res.status(200).send(true);
 });
```

but I want add the checking inside the function `validate`, is there a way to do that? Sorry if this question could be stupid, but I'm new to `NodeJS`

Comment: @NikKyriakides I know how to do this in javascript callback, I just want to know how to do this in mongoose

Comment: Apologies. Retracting.

Comment: @NikKyriakides no problem :)

Comment: @sfarzoso, if you are new to Node (and javascript in general), you should realize that asynchronous is a feature, not a problem.

Comment: @MattKuhns I know javascript, I'm just new to Node :) I really enjoy the Node technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nothing's inherently making `exports.save` synchronous, it's probably easiest to make `validate` asynchronous (and let's also make it modern by using promises and `async`).

```
exports.save = async function(req, res) {
  const errors = await validate(req.body);

  if (!errors.length) {
    //add user
    res.status(200).send(true);
  } else {
    res.status(500).send("oh bad");
  }
};

async function validate(body) {
  const errors = [];
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: body.email });
  if (user) {
    errors.push({ msg: "Email already registered!" });
  }
  return errors;
}
```

Comment: In other words, you can't do this in a strict synchronous sense.

Comment: Yep, which is a good thing. After all, synchronous operations in a Node.js server app would block it from serving other requests, as Node is single-threaded.